# Is it possible to create ASP.NET MVC applications in VS 2010 B1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to create ASP.NET MVC applications in VS 2010? 
What should I do to enable 'Create View', 'Create Controller' magic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Phil Haack talks about this in his latest blog post.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to [wait](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible, makes no sense to use unreleased product. There was enough work migrating from MVC to beta, then to RC1. Who knows what changes the release of VS will bring?

I heard they promised support in Beta 2.

[ASP.NET MVC For Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/18/aspnetmvc-vs2010-beta1.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this logic.  Given that MVC 1.0 is a released product, why should it really matter that you might be using a beta of Visual Studio to develop it?  I guess you might have to manually edit some project files down the road in the worst-case scenario, but it's possible that the benefits of using a beta tool could outweigh this future pootential hassle.